# Bck2Brwsr together with JavaFX?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx-8, bck2brwsr

Has anyone managed to get [Bck2Brwsr](http://wiki.apidesign.org/wiki/Bck2Brwsr) working together with Java 8 / JavaFX 8 lately? Is there a chance of compatibility? I couldn't find much information about it and lack of a good starting point. With the given [Maven archetype](http://wiki.apidesign.org/wiki/Knockout4Java) I get several compilation errors.

How could a minimal project setup look like that actually works? (I'm using Eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these instructions: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bck2brwsr/Ck_FF-V-rlA/j8DnLo7hAfkJ

You can use M2Eclipse to use Maven in Eclipse.